# vsto installer - silent mode problem

Tags: vsto, installation, silent

**Background:**
I am making a VSTO 4.0 add in for Outlook 2007 which enables users to transfer their mail items to a CRM database.

**Requirements:**
The installation has to be silent without users knowledge. It will be in a Custom Action in the Installer class or will run from shell command.

**The problem:**
The installation occurs in silent mode but doesn't actually install the add in.
The installation in non-silent mode completes successfully (but user gets a prompt)

**Security:**
The manifests are signed with a enterprise-trusted certificate (*.pfx)

**Error log:**
Message for silent installation:
*Exception: Customized functionality in this application will not work because it has not been granted trust. The certificate used to sign the deployment manifest is unknown, and the customization itself (FulcrumAddin) is not on the inclusion list. Contact your administrator for further assistance.*

**Final question:**
What are the requirements for the silent install to happen. What is the inclusion list (from: error log) and how does it help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok pretty simple mate, you just need to add the customInclusionList project to your solution.
see this link for VSTO 3.0 i think (haven't started on 4.0) its the same for 4.0

You'll need to add the IncludionList output to the setup project and there are some steps for adding the RSAKey value from the primary projects .VSTO manifest to the installerclass code then making sure you add the inclusionlist output in the setup project to each of the "states" Install, rollback, uninstall, etc.
read the link it makes more sense than i do...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608607.aspx

Also note that if you decide to deploy via MSI instead of clickonce, and you install to Program files (as admin, for instance using SCCM or similiar mechanism) you are Automatically granted Full Trust. this could be another way around your problem...

Comment: Trying this out now - thanks for the answer - I hope it is the final resolution :)